# camera preview on android - strange lines on 1.5 version of sdk

Tags: android, camera

I am developing the camera module for an android application.
In main application when user clicks on 'take picture' button, new view with SurfaceView control is opened and camera preview is shown. When users click on dpad center, camera takes picture and save it to the disc. Pretty simple and straightforward.

Everything works fine on my device - HTC Tattoo, minsdkversion 1.6

...but when I tested application on HTC Hero minsdkversion 1.5, when camera preview is shown,some strange lines occur.

Anyone has idea what is going on?

p.s. altough preview is crashed, taking of pictures works fine

here is the picture[alt text http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/4088/camerademo.jpg](http://img163.imageshack.us/img163/4088/camerademo.jpg):

Thanx
Marko

Comment: Not sure what you mean by strange lines. Can you take a screenshot using DDMS and post it here?

Comment: here is the picture of these strange lines...anyone had similar issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently this is hero bug, in function surfaceChanged switch width and height parameters:

```
    if (getResources().getConfiguration().orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) 
    { 
        parameters.setPreviewSize(h, w); //instead of w,h
    }
```