# Android - picture taken different from preview

Tags: android, image, camera, preview

I have a camera app, in it's simplest state it's nothing more then the cameraPreview example with some 'takePicture' code. The link to the example online is for 2.0, and i'm developping against 1.5 (API lvl 3), but still, here it is: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/CameraPreview.html

The biggest difference with the old version is the whole "getOptimalPreviewSize" thing.
Everything is done landscape.

Now the problem is: i have a preview, but when i take the picture there is more information on that picture then there is on the preview. The top and bottom show stuff that wasn't visible on the preview.

Now i am going to put an overlay on top of the preview, to align the object in the picture with something. If the picture is taken, the whole thing gets squeezed a bit, and i'm all out of alignment :(.

The camera app on the system doesn't have this problem, so it must be possible to fix this. Any thoughts?

If i must manually set the preview and/or picture size, i'll have trouble with different handsets i guess, and because there are a lot of function only since API lvl 5 (e.g.: getOptimalPreviewSize), I can't use these.

Comment: There are even differences among devices running the same Android version, i.e. 2.1update1. In my case I had trouble/differences with HTC Desire/Nexus One vs. Samsung Galaxy S, see this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3213741/camera-preview-on-android-strange-on-samsung-galaxy-s

Comment: I'm not doing anything with the portait and rotation because of issues like that at the moment :( . I can't use the getSupportedPreviewSizes functions because of the 1.5 version i'm running against.

Answer (score 4):

Having built a custom camera app for Android, I know exactly what you are going through. Android 1.5 makes up only 1.1% of the Android users as of 10/29/2011. You will be better off jumping up to at least API level 5. If you want to support portrait and landscape previews consistently on all devices, I recommend you go even higher.

Make use of the getSupportedPreviewSizes() and getSupportedPicturesSizes(). These functions tell you exactly what the camera supports (varies by phone/manufacturer). Run through the enumerations and find values that match from both. Use the one that suits you best.

Word of warning: Failure to set preview and picture sizes that are actually supported can cause your app to crash on certain devices. I've seen this first hand.

[reference to 1.5 Android users](http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html)

Answer (score 1):

The largest preview size returned by `getSupportedPicturSizes` represents the native resolution of your camera. If the aspect ratio of that size differs from your preview size or the picture size that you set your `Camera` object to then then cropping will occur. You can compare the aspect ratios to determine how much will be cropped and in which direction.(top/bottom vs left/right)